# Return Map of Map without side-effects using Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

How do I put/add `eServiceReportsMapByBatchFile` with key `oldReportId` to `eServiceReportMap` without side-effects?

```
Map<String, Map<String, Set<EServiceReport>>> eServiceReportMap = new HashMap<>();
reports.forEach(report -> {
    String oldReportId = report.getOldId();
        Map<String, Set<EServiceReport>> eServiceReportsMapByBatchFile = // processing of batch files
        ...
    eServiceReportMap.put(oldReportId, eServiceReportsMapByBatchFile);
});

return eServiceReportMap;
```

That is, I want it to become like this:

```
return reports.stream()
    .map(report -> {
        String oldReportId = report.getOldId();
        Map<String, Set<EServiceReport>> eServiceReportsMapByBatchFile = // processing of batch files
        ...
        // I don't know how and what to return here
    }).collect(// I don't know what to do here);
```

Thank you.

Comment: what is `reports`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking forward mostly to `Collectors.toMap` which can be used as :

```
return reports.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(report -> report.getOldId(),
                        report -> {
                    // batch processing for eServiceReportsMapByBatchFile
                            return eServiceReportsMapByBatchFile;
                }));
```

Answer (score 3):

since you call `stream` on `reports`, I assume it is a collection of some kind; in such case there is nothing wrong with your side-effects. Notice that `someCollection.stream().forEach` and `someCollection.forEach` are very different things, you are more than OK to have side-effects with `SomeCollection::forEach` - which is nothing but a plain old loop internally.

You *could* transform that that to a stream solution, but it's going to be a lot less readable:

```
reports.stream()
       .map(r -> {
            String oldReportId = report.getOldId();
            Map<String, Set<EServiceReport>> eServiceReportsMapByBatchFile =....  
            return new SimpleEntry<>(oldReportId, eServiceReportsMapByBatchFile);
       })
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Entry::getKey,
            Entry::getValue,
            (left, right) -> right; // to match whatever you had until now
       ))
```